# Como agrupar por 2 propriedades e somar os valores

Tags: c#, linq, winforms

Não faço ideia como fazer essa consulta em LINQ. Como posso a partir de lista de vendas. Separar as vendas por hora, e então agrupar os produtos e somar as quantidades vendidas?

```
 public class Venda
 {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public DateTime DataHora {get;set;}
   public List<ProdutoVendido> ProdutosVendidos {get;set;}
 }

 public class ProdutoVendido
 {
   public Produto Produto {get;set;}
   public int Quantidade {get;set;}
 }

 public class Produto
 {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
 }
```

**Em SQL ficaria assim:**

```
select hour(dthr_venda), nm_produto, sum(cd_qt) from produto_e_venda
join venda using(cd_venda)
join produto using (cd_produto)
group by cd_produto, hour(dthr_venda)
order by 1;
```

Comment: produto_e_venda é a classe ProdutoVendido?

Comment: ProdutoVendido refere-se a tabela produto_e_venda sim (:

Comment: O modelo parece errado, e você ta usando Entity ?

Comment: Eu simplifiquei, existem outras propriedades.

Comment: Mas a ProdutoVendido não tem Id?

Comment: Não por que essa tabela possui duas chaves primárias, sendo código da venda e código do produto. Estou usando também fluent nhibernate pra fazer as classes

Comment: Coloque os códigos por completo se não fica difícil responder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query para agrupar cada produto por hora e calcular as quantidades vendidas será:

```
var vendasPorProduto = vendas.GroupBy(v => v.DataHora.Hour)
                                .Select(g => new
                                    {
                                        Hora = g.Key,
                                        ProdutosDetalhados = g.SelectMany(v => v.ProdutosVendidos)
                                                            .GroupBy(pv => pv.Produto)
                                                            .Select(v => new
                                                                {
                                                                    Produto = v.Key,
                                                                    Quantidade = v.Sum(pv => pv.Quantidade)
                                                                })
                                    });
```

**Extra:**

Se quiser calcular a totalidade de produtos vendidos numa hora (foi o produto secundário de responder à sua pergunta):

```
var todosProdutosPorHora = vendas.GroupBy(v => v.DataHora.Hour)
                                    .Select(g => new
                                        {
                                            Hora = g.Key,
                                            Total = g.Sum(venda =>
                                                        venda.ProdutosVendidos.Sum(pv => pv.Quantidade))
                                        });
```